# How to show diff between 2 rich texts like we use to see on github but only want to see text not the html tags (on react js)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

to see the expected results go to

[image]

```
old text and new text are given down
old Text : <div>hello<br>this<br>is a</div>
new Text : <div>hello<br>this<br>is a sample text</div>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.